# Android Edittext - detect when first non-empty character entered (and last deleted)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to execute a method **only when first non-empty character** is entered in `Edittext` or last non-empty character deleted. I think I have to use `TextWatcher` but not sure about the logic.

Comment: What exactly are you not sure about? There are plenty of examples

Answer (score 2):

Use `addTextChangedListener` for Edittext and detect first character inserted with `charSequence.length() > 0` condition!

```
      <YOUR_EDITTEXT>.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                int length = charSequence.toString().trim().length();
                if ((length == 1 && (i == 0 && i1 < i2)) || (length == 0 && (i == 0 && i2 < i1))) {
                    //Call your method....
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: This won't work. Only when **first** non-empty character is entered.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail when there are 2 characters and one is deleted?

Comment: @thetanuj no, trim() method will remove whitespace characters and you can detect first non-empty character with length of 1 condition.

Comment: @Ahmed Correct. But after first char, if I enter a second character and delete the second character, then `charSequence.toString().trim().length() == 1` will return `true` which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to trim your EditText string. trim function delete all the white spaces at the beginning and end.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){                           
     int length = charSequence.toString().trim().length();
     if(length > 0){
         // call your method
     }
}
```

Comment: I get that but this will cause the method to execute every time a non-empty character is entered which is not the requirement.

Comment: Which method you refer to? Are you talking about `if` condition then it won't affect your app performance.

Comment: just add this inside your `onTextChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, You can do this by using TextWatcher.

Logic: declare a variable to store last value in edittext, let's say temp

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            // when first non-empty character is entered
            if(s.length()>temp.length() && s != ' ' && temp.length()==0) {
                //Call your method
            }
            // when last non-empty character is deleted
            if(s.length()<temp.length() && s!=' ' && temp.length()==1){
                //Call your method
            }
        }
```

also save new value in temp variable. Hope it will help.